# run a python script in background and restart it on crash

Tags: ubuntu, python, monitoring

I have a very simple Python script that I'd like to be always running on my ubuntu 12.04 server. I thought of using upstart + monit. Problem is that those tools seem rather complicated for a simple mortal like me, and I cannot find a simple example on the web.

Is upstart + monit overkill ? / Does somebody know a simpler alternative ? / or a good tutorial ?

Comment: As I just want the script to be running, isn't upstart enough ? Monit is needed only to make a test periodically right !?

Comment: For reference, exact same question was asked here: https://askubuntu.com/q/175751/753946

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/697064/1337398):

You could write a bash script `monitor.sh` which starts your python script and restarts it if it crashes but doesn't restart if the script exits normally:

```
#!/bin/bash
until myscript.py; do
    echo "'myscript.py' crashed with exit code $?. Restarting..." >&2
    sleep 1
done
```

Then just start the monitor script in background:

```
nohup monitor.sh &
```

As an alternative to `nohup`, you may also consider [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) for running background processes.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is great. I can't comment as of now so maybe improve the answer here.

You might even want to write a function for "myscript" as it is a python script and not running under the bash env.

So,

```
#!/bin/bash

myscript(){
    python3 myscript [args..]
}

until myscript; do
    echo "'myscript' crashed with exit code $?. Restarting..." >&2
    sleep 1
done
```

New people to python or bash wouldn't know this small thing. Might help them. I used to struggle with such small stuff in the beginning. Do not want any others to!

Comment: Completely unnecessary if the python script has the proper [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). And this shebang will indicate the proper Python version.

Comment: And what if it doesn't?

Comment: I post stuff sometimes in pretext of making newbies understand if their thing doesn't work. Everyone doesn't necessarily need to know what a shebang is.

Comment: *And what if it doesn't?* Then you add one.